# Simplifying code using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I wanted to find out whether it was possible to use a loop to simplify all this rather than hard-coding the entire structure. For the second part of my Javascript where I tried to store the user inputs into localStorage using a for loop, I'm getting an error where it says

CreateEvent.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: name.push  is not a function at createReplace (CreateEvent.js:72) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (CreateEvent.html:130)

HTML:

```
<span class="border1">
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title!">
        <p id="title1"></p>
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="brief" placeholder="Enter brief description!">
        <p id="brief1"></p>
</span>

<div class="Hovertrees">
    <p>Hover over me!</p>
    <span class="Hovertrees2">
    <input class="hover" type="text" id="hover" placeholder="Enter some fun facts!">
        <p id="hover1"></p>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="what">
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="whattitle" placeholder="What is this event?">
        <h2 id="whattitle1"></h2>
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="whatdesc" placeholder="Enter brief description!">
        <p id="whatdesc1"></p>
</div>

<div id="why">
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="whytitle" placeholder="Why is this event important?">
        <h2 id="whytitle1"></h2>
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="whydesc" placeholder="Description of this event">
        <p id="whydesc1"></p>
</div>

<div id="fun">
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="funtitle" placeholder="Anything interesting you can add!">
        <h3 id="funtitle1"></h3>
    <input class="forms" type="text" id="fundesc" placeholder="Description of the interesting info!">
        <p id="fundesc1"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var title;
var brief;
var hover;
var whatTitle;
var whatDesc;
var whyTitle;
var whyDesc;
var funTitle;
var funDesc;

function createReplace() {
    title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById('title').className = 'hidden';

    document.getElementById('news').innerHTML = title;

    brief = document.getElementById('brief').value;
    document.getElementById('brief1').innerHTML = brief;
    document.getElementById('brief').className = 'hidden';

    hover = document.getElementById('hover').value;
    document.getElementById('hover1').innerHTML = hover;
    document.getElementById('hover').className = 'hidden';

    whatTitle = document.getElementById('whattitle').value;
    document.getElementById('whattitle1').innerHTML = whatTitle;
    document.getElementById('whattitle').className = 'hidden';

    whatDesc = document.getElementById('whatdesc').value;
    document.getElementById('whatdesc1').innerHTML = whatDesc;
    document.getElementById('whatdesc').className = 'hidden';

    whyTitle = document.getElementById('whytitle').value;
    document.getElementById('whytitle1').innerHTML = whyTitle;
    document.getElementById('whytitle').className = 'hidden';

    whyDesc = document.getElementById('whydesc').value;
    document.getElementById('whydesc1').innerHTML = whyDesc;
    document.getElementById('whydesc').className = 'hidden';

    funTitle = document.getElementById('funtitle').value;
    document.getElementById('funtitle1').innerHTML = funTitle;
    document.getElementById('funtitle').className = 'hidden';

    funDesc = document.getElementById('fundesc').value;
    document.getElementById('fundesc1').innerHTML = funDesc;
    document.getElementById('fundesc').className = 'hidden';

    document.getElementById("create").className = "hidden";

    var varNames = [
        'titles',
        'brief',
        'hover',
        'whatTitle',
        'whatDesc',
        'whyTitle',
        'funtitle',
        'fundesc'
    ]
    for (var name in varNames) {
        var value = window[name]
        var obj = {name : value};
            if(localStorage.getItem(name) != null) {
                var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
                for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
                    name.push(tmp[i]);
                }

            }
            name.push(obj);
            localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is correct name is not an array. What do you get in `value`?

Comment: @Jai value is supposed to give me the value of my variable 'title'

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, simplifying is not possible since you have different properties for each elements.

---

For the second part, you are getting error because push is a method for array object.But **name** is an string object declared in for loop

```
for (var name in varNames) {
        var value = window[name]
        var obj = {name : value};
            if(localStorage.getItem(name) != null) {
                var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
                for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
                    name.push(tmp[i]);
                }

            }
            name.push(obj);
            localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: ahh I see, but how am I supposed to get the value to push into the array then?

Comment: I do not understand what exactly are you trying to do in this for loop.

Comment: The for loop is to increase the index of the array so when the function starts, the value replaces that new empty index rather than replace the original index

Answer (score 0):

You can set item in loop

```
localStorage.setItem(1,'name1');
localStorage.setItem(2,'name2');
localStorage.setItem(3,'name2');
```

1 2 and 3 would be key that you want to set and then  get according to these keys.

```
localStorage.key(index)
```

By passing index in key method it will return you the  value of that key.

Comment: I don't really understand this? Do you mind explaining in detail?

Comment: If you are setting the item in localStorage in loop then you can use key like 'name_'+'i' in loop and i would be loop increment id by which you can set names on different keys and get one by one by calling using same keys that used to set items.